# How to remove � from a csv download?

Tags: csv, google-sheets, ascii

I'm downloading a CSV file, but all the spaces get turned into a �.
I realise its a difference in the ASCII code or simply a print instruction.
But anyone know how to download with a regular char 32 space istead of the �?

```
function importCSV() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Make the first sheet the active sheet
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);

  var cell = ss.getRange("SettingsManualInputs!D3");      //Get the clan name from cell D3
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();


  var rsurl = "http://services.runescape.com/m=clan-hiscores/members_lite.ws?clanName="; // set up the url address
  var csvUrl = rsurl+cellValue;

  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();     // call data from url in csv format                                   

  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Make the second sheet the active sheet
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();    // select active sheet and get csv clan data pasted into cell B2
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

I would post a demo, but it does not let me (not enough reputation).

Comment: Most likely an encoding issue. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Comment: In its response header, the server does not indicate the character encoding and also uses a strange content type (text/comma-separated-values), so check its documentation. Once you know which "charset" it is you can tell [getContentText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getContentText(String)).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with var cellValue ="test" and the results I got had no "�" character. However, if you have that character you can add another sheet and replace the character like this:

```
=arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!A:E,"�"," "))
```

You might be able to do the substitute when you bring the file in, but I don't have a good way to test that.

Comment: Thank you and yes I already come up with posting the cleaned substituted data onto another sheet now. Glad I come up with the same idea.
As a side note, I could not find any ascii code to match the � character.
I think its a null printer code?
However even though this fix isn't tidy or a script code fix. I do have my data.
Many thanks for your assistance.